# Codename One Storage behavior on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: codenameone

In my app, some data is streamed into the device with a timestamp, so I store it in a Hashtable structure. If the user desires, it is also saved to storage for later viewing or e-mailing as a CSV file. This works fine on iOS devices, and two different (non-Samsung) brands of Android devices running 4.4 and 6.0. It does not work on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running 5.0.1.

The program works as follows, after the user presses the stop button, the following method is called:

```
public void stopLogging() {
    isLogging = false;
    dataStorage.flushStorageCache();
    dataStorage.writeObject(fileName, dataLogValues);
    dataLogValues.clear();
}
```

dataLogValues is the Hashtable.

When it's time to access the logged data, a list of the available filenames is collected with buttons to enable accessing a particular log.

```
public String[] getLogList() {
    return dataStorage.listEntries();
}
```

Where dataStorage was previously initialized in the constructor

```
dataStorage = Storage.getInstance();
```

When a log is selected from the String[] of the storage entries, the following method is called to retrieve the file:

```
public Hashtable<Long, Integer> getLog(String logName) {
    dataStorage.clearCache();
    Hashtable<Long, Integer> log = (Hashtable<Long, Integer>) dataStorage
            .readObject(logName);
    return log;
}
```

On the Samsung device, I added a dialog to show each log file name as I iterate through the String[] of entry names, and I only get the following:

"rList-(full package name).RallyPacControlStub" where RallyPacControl is the app's name. If I also display the size of the String[], I get the expected number of entries for how many logs I saved. Here is the code where I handle the log entries, and avoid files I don't want. The log files that are created for this are just named by a time/date string signifying the creation time.

```
String[] logList = dataBuffer.getLogList();
    for (int i = 0; i < logList.length; i++) {
        Dialog.show("Log name", logList[i], "OK", null);
        if (!logList[i].equalsIgnoreCase("Cookies")
                && !logList[i].startsWith("CN1")
                && !logList[i].equals("Infopage")
                && !logList[i].startsWith("Chart")
                && !logList[i].startsWith("Log")) {
            String log = logList[i];
            Container buttonContainer = new Container();
            buttonContainer.setUIID("LogButtonContainer");
            buttonContainer.setName("LogListContainer");
            buttonContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            buttonContainer.add(new ShowLogButton(log, dataBuffer
                    .getLog(logList[i])));
            buttonContainer.add(new ExportLogButton((logList[i])));
            buttonContainer.add(new LogDeleteButton(log, this));
            logsContainer.add(buttonContainer);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In 9 out of 10 cases like this the problem relates to users expecting `getClass().getName()` to return a valid value. None of this seems relevant to the problem as you don't show any of the code that accesses the storage and even the way that the storage fails isn't very clear.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I've shown all the code that accesses storage. The dataStorage variable holds a reference to Storage.getInstance(). I use the writeObject and readObject methods to store and retrieve. I use listEntries to get a list of the file names. On most devices, after doing this the String array returned by listEntries has the expected keys that were used to put the items into Storage. On the Samsung device, I only get result I stated above. I'm not experienced on building Android apps from sources but I guess I'll need to try it to get a better log of what's happening.

Comment: It looks like I can get around this problem by adding a known prefix to the file name and then only using items from Storage with that prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must have missed the line with the `Hashtable` read. It's possible that the Samsung device has a hidden file in the hierarchy to indicate filesystem meta-data that might be accessible to you so using a file prefix is generally a good idea.

It's also possible that this is the file from the `Log.p()` API that gets written to that location. Notice that the `Storage` API doesn't guarantee that only the files you write into storage are returned.